# Text overflow when using nvarchar(max)?

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2005

I've run into a strange situation that seems to involve long text overflowing. I'm using `fn_pcre_replace` (from the [xp_pcre extended stored procedure](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/xp_pcre.aspx)) on an `nvarchar(max)` column, and when I replace with more characters than were there originally, it returns NULL if the original string was over 8000 characters long.

For example, this

```
Select master.dbo.fn_pcre_replace(Overview,'a', 'X')
from ProjectContent
```

works as expected, but this

```
Select master.dbo.fn_pcre_replace(Overview,'a', 'XXX')
from ProjectContent
```

returns NULL in most cases (apparently, wherever `Len(Overview)>8000`).

Is this a limitation of `xp_pcre`, or is there something I can do in my SQL to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of `xp_pcre`.  Looking at the source:

```
    switch (bType)
    {
    case SRVBIGCHAR:
    case SRVBIGVARCHAR:
        break;
    default:
        throw XpException(
            StringBuilder()
            << "Invalid data type on parameter "
            << paramNum
            << " (should be CHAR or VARCHAR)."
            );
    }
```

I can conclude these two values (from `<srv.h>`) permit up to a maximum of 8000 characters.  [SRVBIGVARCHAR is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216035(SQL.80).aspx)

> Variable-length character data type,
>   length 0 to 8000 bytes.

You would need to update the source and recompile with support for SRVTEXT or SRVVARCHAR so it is not a limiting factor when using external procedures.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll just do the cleanup in .NET rather than SQL.